# PowerApps DLP not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

Signed in as the tenant admin, I went to the PowerApps admin center and created a new Data Policy affecting all environments. I added "SharePoint" to the "Business Data Only" section and nothing else.

Logged in as a different user, I created a new flow that used a SharePoint trigger and emailed data from the modified SharePoint list item, and the workflow worked fine.

I was expecting the Flow to be disabled, as I expected the use of both a SharePoint and Email action in the same flow to be blocked due to the DLP Policy.

Did I do something wrong in setting up the policy, or do I not understand the role of these DLP policies?